# Small generating set for the unique minimal prime ideal of a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian, algebras

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, generated by $n$ elements ($n$ finite). Assume that $A$ has a unique minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Write $t$ for the minimal number of generators for the ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.

> Can we bound $t$ in terms of $n$?

I assume this is either false, or a special case of something much more general. In the latter case, maybe there's a simple proof for this special case? I'm not asking for the best possible bound (but it would be nice if the bound is pretty good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples by Macaulay of prime ideals of height two in polynomial ring $R$ in three variables over a field which require large number of generators. If $P$ is one such, taking the ring $R/P^{(n)}$ for large enough $n$, you will have such examples showing no such bound can exist.

Comment: Thank you! Is the example the same as in: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206899/macaulays-example-of-prime-ideals-in-mathbb-cx-1-x-2-x-3-having-large-numb ?

Comment: @Object Yes, same example.